# Why has my UIViewController lost reference to open modal ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have a view controller which checks if a user is currently authenticated. If not I present a login view controller modally.

```
-(void)showLoginView{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [self storyboard];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController  = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    loginViewController.parentController = self;
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Once the user has authenticated I would like to dismiss the modal login view controller but from some reason the parent view controller has lost reference to the modal controller. The login view controller begins the process of opening a session using the Facebook SDK. Facebook will open it's own web view for user authentication. Could this be responsible?

```
-(void)loginSuccess{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If the user has successfully authenticated the modal login view calls the above method on the parent view controller. However self.presentingViewController is nil. So the modal view is never dismissed. Can someone help tell what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oi! I'm dumb. I was trying this:

```
-(void)loginSuccess{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This SHOULD be:

```
-(void)loginSuccess{
    [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Notice the difference between 'presentingViewController' and 'presentedViewController'.

Comment: The presented view controller will just forward the message back to the presenting view controller, so you should just write [self dismiss....